# How to "fake" a module safely in a Python package

Tags: python, git, package, setuptools

Currently I have the following directory structure in the master `git` branch:

```
/dir1
    __init__.py
    module.py
```

This will be changed to (in my branch):

```
/dir1
    __init__.py
    /dir2
        module1.py # With 70% of code of module.py
        module2.py # With 30% of code of module.py
```

Issues:

1. I know its not possible to make `git` track both new files, but since `git` recognizes renames (and it considers organizing into folders as renames) I will be able to track changes to `module.py` from the master branch to my branch's `module1.py`, at least for the 70% of the code (I'll have to update `module2.py` manually). So is there a better way to deal with this?
2. For API consistency, I'd like people who use older version of my package to still use `from dir1.module import abc` (without having a `module.py` in `dir1`) This can be done like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122465/can-i-fake-a-package-or-at-least-a-module-in-python-for-testing-purposes), but that comes with the dangers of messing with the `sys` path variables, which is not advised for stability and safety considerations. Is there a better way I could make the API backward-compatible and still safe/stable?

---

However, my situation is more complex. For a more representative example, consider moving from:

```
/dir1
    __init__.py
    module_2.py
        def add2(a, b):
            return a + b
        def sub2(a, b):
            return a - b
    module_3.py
        def add3(a, b, c):
            return a + b + c
```

to:

```
/dir1
    __init__.py
    /dir2
        __init__.py
        module_add.py
            # ... Constitutes 70% of code from `dir1/module_2.py`
            def add2(a, b):
                return a + b
            # A few more additional lines added from `dir1/module_3.py`
            def add3(a, b, c):
                return a + b + c
        module_sub.py
            # Constitutes the 30% from /dir1/module2.py
            def sub2(a, b):
                return a - b
```

So in essence I am splitting up the different functionalities of `dir1/module_2.py` and `dir1/module_3.py` and regrouping them into separate `module_add.py` and `module_sub.py` and putting it under `/dir1/dir2`

However, version 1 users getting the version 2 package should still be able to do:

```
from module_2 import add2, sub2
from module_3 import add3
```

Things I can't do:

- Have `module_2.py` or `module_3.py` in `dir1` (I need git to associate and track the master branch's `dir1/module_2.py` to `dir1/dir2/module_2.py` of my branch);
- Change or mess around `sys.path` in any way that reduces stability/safety; or
- Rename `dir2` to e.g. `module_2`.

Comment: Do you really need to avoid having `module.py`?  You could just make a `module.py` that does `from dir2.module1 import *` and `from dir2.module2 import *`.

Comment: @BrenBarn that is the current setup... :)
not having `module.py` defined helps me track changes ( atleast the 70% ) to `modue.py` at master to my branch's `dir2/module1.py`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe that breaks the API's backward compat ;)

Comment: If previously they did `from dir1.module import abc` I don't  want them to now do `from dir1.dir2.module1 import abc` **or** `from dir1 import abc`...The reason why I need this is, the work is for an open source package which is well maintained and popularly used... It requires at least 2 release cycles to force users to do `from dir1.dir2.module1 import abc` or `from dir1 import abc`... So need a clean way to keep it backward compatible... ( and trackable via git for my / other dev convenience )

Comment: Ah thats clever ;) really sorry though, the structure is a tad more complex and `dir2` is an aggregation of several such `module`-s... thanks for patiently responding though :)

Comment: Then could you possibly provide an example that's *actually representative of what you're trying to do*? It might be that the answer is just *not* to try to move these disparate items into `dir2`, precisely *because* it will break the API. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/28180879/3001761

Comment: *"Things I can't do ... name `dir2` to `module`"* - could you explain *why not*? The "toy code" is really no more helpful than the original example, as it doesn't demonstrate why the method suggested won't be effective.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I hope this should make it a tad clearer?

Comment: @ragv I have updated my answer to show how the same logic could be applied to your more complex situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the following setup:

```
/dir1
    __init__.py
        from module import abc
    module.py
        abc = None
```

is externally (pretty much) indistinguishable from:

```
/dir1
    __init__.py
        from module import abc
    /module
        __init__.py
           from module1 import abc
        module1.py  # this is the moved and renamed module.py, with git history
            abc = None
        module2.py  # this is the 30% you've factored out
            # whatever's in here
```

From *outside* `module.py`/`module`, the old import `from module import abc` (and `from dir1.module import abc`, etc.) continues to work.

---

For your more complex example, you can still switch from:

```
/dir1
    __init__.py
        from module_2 import add2, sub2
        from module_3 import add3
    module_2.py
    module_3.py
```

to:

```
/dir1
    __init__.py
        from dir2.module_add import add2, add3
        from dir2.module_sub import sub2
    /dir2
        __init__.py
        module_add.py  # module_2.py moved & renamed
        module_sub.py  # module_3.py moved & renamed or new file
    /module_2
        __init__.py
           from ..dir2.module_add import add2
           from ..dir2.module_sub import sub2
    /module_3
        __init__.py
           from ..dir2.module_add import add3
```

The old code (e.g. `from dir1.module_2 import add2`) will still work correctly, but users can now start accessing the new locations (e.g. `from dir1.dir2.module_add import add2, add3`).

---

You can also add e.g.:

```
import warnings
warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
```

to the `__init__.py` files in `/dir1/module_2` and `/dir1/module_3` to provide warnings to users that these imports are now on the way out. For example:

```
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.simplefilter('always')
>>> from dir1.dir2.module_sub import sub2
>>> sub2(1, 2)
-1
>>> from dir1.module_3 import add3

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "dir1\module_3\__init__.py", line 2
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
DeprecationWarning: deprecated
>>> add3(1, 2, 3)
6
```